# Add-on electronic ignition for gas stove?

Tags: gas, stove-top, natural-gas, stove

Is it possible to retrofit electronic ignition into a natural gas stove? Does such a kit exist commercially?

Comment: I think you are going to have to go full on DIY with that one.

Comment: Would a push button ignition be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

We looked at this for a commercial unit in our church, and the consensus was to just buy two residential-class stoves with electronic ignition rather than pay for the retrofit. It was that costly. I would imagine that residential stoves, which aren't designed to be messed around with much, would have a similar problem; you're basically replacing everything from the burners back to the pilot lights. I imagine replacing your pilot-light stove with an electronic-start model would be less expensive, especially if you were able to get some sort of trade-in.